# Access Violation Error for Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I tried running my code, however, I've met a access violation error. I googled for some resource, but it doesn't seems that my code have any problem.
Can someone help me out?

```
void addToEnd(PlayerListNode *newNode){

    if (newNode == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(1);

    }
    printf("\n Inserting %d ... \n", newNode->player);
    PlayerListNode *current = listHead;
    while (current -> next != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = newNode;
}
```

The error happen when the while loop is running.

Comment: `if (newNode == NULL) { printf("ERROR"); }` -- and then go ahead and use it anyway? You need to return or something when that happens.

Comment: Let's `NULL` check `listHead`. (and do `newNode->next = NULL;`)

Comment: @TomZych I've exit the proram.

Comment: Are the passed pointers valid? Also a newly created pointer may point to anything but Null so your check will not work. Ensure you have initd correctly what your are passing.  I think you should copy the data. What if your data becomes invalid outside the function; Just A thought...

Comment: @Gerstrong I don't get what you mean

Comment: what if `listHead` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution is based on my guessing

```
void addToEnd(PlayerListNode *newNode){

    if (newNode == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(1);

    }

    if(!listHead){
       printf("\n First node %d inserted... \n", newNode->player);
       listHead=newNode;
       return;
    }

    printf("\n Inserting %d ... \n", newNode->player);
    PlayerListNode *current = listHead;
    while (current -> next != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = newNode;
}
```

since you are inserting to the end of the tree, it can be optimized by adding lastNode member to the PlayerListNode;

```
void addToEnd(PlayerListNode *newNode){

    if (newNode == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(1);

    }

    if(!listHead){
       printf("\n First node %d inserted... \n", newNode->player);
       listHead=newNode;
    }
    listHead->LastNode->next = newNode;
    listHead->LastNode=newNode;
    listHead->LastNode->next = NULL; //unsure it is NULL in case of newNode is listHead
}
```